# PySide2: How to get column values of QTableWidget as a list?

Tags: python, pyside2

I'm trying to extract all values contained on a `PySide2.QtWidgets.QTableWidget` column. For the moment I'm using this piece of code:

```
table = PySide2.QtWidgets.QTableWidget()

''' Different code here where table is modified
'''

column = 5
listValues = [ table.item(row, column).text() for row in range(table.rowCount()) ]
```

Is there any PySide method to extract the values directly?

Comment: no, there is no short form